# What do the backticks in build.gradle.kts do?

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have the following in my `build.gradle.kts` Gradle build file:

```kotlin
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.6.10"
    id("maven-publish")
    `java-gradle-plugin`
}
```

Of particular interest is the `kotlin-dsl` and `java-gradle-plugin`.  I understand that backticks enable you to create identifiers that are normally invalid syntax.  So in this case it's the `-` in the name makes this required.  But what exactly is happening here when I put those lines in?  I'm just typing out that variable.  I'm not assigning it to anything, using as an argument to a function, or doing anything that looks like I'm configuring something.

What is actually happening on those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing, different way to apply it in Kotlin.  `id(...)` applies based on a string.  May be required for less well-known plugins.  Without the `id`, you're applying the plugin "directly", so to speak.

You can see here, this is the recommended method for application according to Gradle docs:

> https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_gradle_plugin.html

You can apply the `maven-publish` plugin the same way--make it not a string, and surround with back-ticks (since the dash would break that one as well).

---

Internally, by introspecting into the method from within IntelliJ, it appears that the explicit implementation is merely a convenience method which has an `inline` that calls `id(...)` for you.

```kotlin
/**
 * The builtin Gradle plugin implemented by [org.gradle.plugin.devel.plugins.JavaGradlePluginPlugin].
 *
 * @see org.gradle.plugin.devel.plugins.JavaGradlePluginPlugin
 */
inline val org.gradle.plugin.use.PluginDependenciesSpec.`java-gradle-plugin`: org.gradle.plugin.use.PluginDependencySpec
    get() = id("org.gradle.java-gradle-plugin")
```

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  I understand that having `\`kotlin-dsl\`` in my `plugins` section configures that plugin, but _how_?  It's just a property/variable, right?  `id(...)` makes sense.  You're calling a `fun` and `fun`'s do something.  If I wrote `\`fooBar\`` in the `plugins` section I would expect to just apply the `fooBar` plugin.  What's the magic here?

Comment: Updated.  Added more explicit context on what it's doing behind the curtain.

Comment: Oh, I see.  You're accessing a property with a `get() = ...` getter method.  And this getter has the side effect of applying the plugin.  Not gonna like, I really dislike that.  Accessing a property for the sole purpose of causing such a side-effect just feels...wrong.  But at-least I understand it now.